# Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results to it error in Authorize.Net SIM

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, http-post, checkout, authorize.net

I am trying to get response data posted by Authorize.Net on relay URL in classic ASP. The code was working perfect, but suddenly stopped working when I migrated my sites to different server. I have updated setting in Authorize.Net.

PS: It's posting fine on Data Validation URL - 
https://developer.authorize.net/tools/paramdump/index.php

I am getting the following error -

> An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the
>   merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of
>   the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your
>   credit card.
>
> ```
>   This transaction has been approved.
> ```
>
> It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you
>   will receive the product or service.

At merchant email, I am receiving following error message notification -

> Authorize.Net Developer Center Merchant,
>
> Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results
>   to it.    Transaction ID: 2217107375
>
> Transaction Result: This transaction has been approved.
>
> The following message was displayed to the customer:
>
> ------------------------------An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the
>   merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of
>   the attempt to charge your credit card.
>
> This transaction has been approved.
>
> It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you
>   will receive the product or service.

Comment: Have you checked with your new hosting provider to see if perhaps they are blocking the POST?  You should also ensure that the URL POSTs to a standard port (80, 443).

Comment: @rhldr, Yes, i have discussed with them and its all open, also i confirmed that there is no proxy blocking to get POST response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorize.Net Direct Post for Magento - An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456805/authorize-net-direct-post-for-magento-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-report)