# Authorize.Net Direct Post for Magento - An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Authorize.Net Direct Post for Magento

Getting below error.

> An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the
>   merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of
>   the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your
>   credit card.
>
> This transaction has been approved.
>
> It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you
>   will receive the product or service.

Answer (score 1):

This means the relay response URL used by Magento/your website is not returning a successful response to Authorize.Net in time (5 seconds). As a result Authorize.Net is assuming the page is not functioning and displaying that message.

You need to verify that the URL you provided is correct, reachable from outside your network, and responding in less than five seconds.